# Multiple for() loop and if() statement

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I need two for loops. Like this:

```
for (i in seq_along(dat1)[25:30]) 
    for(j in seq_along(dat1)[2:7]) {
        print(summary(r <- lm(dat1[,j] ~ dat1[,i]+Jan+Nov, data=dat1)))
}
```

Now I would like to condition the output, that I only get the diagonals and not all possible permutations, so the first of `i` and the first of `j`. How do I do this?

I tried the if statement but `if (i==j)` doesn't work and I don't know how to specify it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `if ((i-23) == j)`. But the following command may be easier:

```
mapply(25:30, 2:7, function(i, j)
                             summary(lm(dat1[,j] ~ dat1[,i]+Jan+Nov, data=dat1)))
```

This will avoid the permutations you are not interested in.